# Convertir fecha en string en formato date

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy tratando de convertir el formato de fecha

> 6 de noviembre de 2018

en

> 6/11/2018

de la siguiente forma:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(fecha_inicio_,'%d-%B-%Y')
```

y obtengo el siguiente error, estuve probando otras convinaciones pero siempre obtengo el mismo error.

> ValueError: time data '6 de noviembre de 2018' does not match format
>   '%d- %B-%Y'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `strptime()` tienes que pasarle la cadena que especifica el formato en que se supone que está tu texto. Has puesto `"%d-%B-%Y"`, pero ese no es el formato del texto, sino que sería `"%d de %B de %Y"`.

No obstante, ya que el nombre del mes aparece en español en tu texto, tendrás que asegurarte de haber configurado el `locale` de ese idioma. De lo contrario posiblemente `strptime()` esperará `november` como nombre de mes y fallará también.

Lo siguiente me funciona:

```
import datetime
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, "es_ES")

fecha = "6 de noviembre de 2018"

t = datetime.datetime.strptime(fecha, "%d de %B de %Y")
print(t)
```

```
2018-11-06 00:00:00
```

Comment: También no está de más avisar que `strptime` espera `septiembre` y no `setiembre` como está hace tiempo aceptado por la RAE, para lo que se puede hacer un reemplazo.

Answer (score 0):

inteta con esto:

```
from datetime import datetime

s = "6 de Noviembre de 2018".replace("de","")
d = datetime.strptime(s, '%d %B %Y')
print(d.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
```